# How should I change the permission?

Tags: permissions, 19.10, chmod

Permission read only doesn't change even as root ubuntu 19.10
.I tried chmod again and again through terminal but nothing happen , I did a this

( ls -dl /media/balla/7EB6D19AB6D152EF

drwxrwxrwx 1 balla balla 65536 ينا 12 23:57 /media/balla/7EB6D19AB6D152EF )

when ever I wrote  ( chmod -R a+rwx /dir*** ) as I lost all hope it still resulted with read only , I can't access any data on the hard disk aside from those at Home , why the commands to change permission fail ?

Comment: From your description, seems like the media is *mounted* read-only. The can happen by design, or due to a fault. The media must be *re-mounted* read-write. If that fails, then the media may be faulty or dying -- look up how to run a SMART test on the media.

Comment: Thnx , remount opened some options that was locked but apparently when I leave the dir it vanish , look like I am on the right road , as for smart test  it's smartctl , right ?